# Process - Python Convert XML File to Multiple Database tables Maintaing relationships

Tags: python, lxml

I am looking for some guidance in how to perform convert an xml file with many columns and rows into a database Postgres or MariaDB splitting the columns into multiple tables and maintaining relationships.

I am looking for an answer that covers process and libraries and any good tutorials on libraries to be used.

Having completed Python on Codeacadamy  and Real Python course. So I know the basics Python, SQL. I am just not able to structure or complete a real world project.

I don't want an answer that you code for me, I want to do the work I can do all the basics.

For example I have read lxml tutorials and they parse an xml but the tutorials don't actually do anything with the parsed code eg prepare it for a database, save the steps to repeat future imports etc.